# Can not boot into Ubuntu after BIOS Update (Dual Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have a Dell XPS 13 9380 that is dualbooted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. I have been using it without issue for about ~6 months. I recently updated my firmware (mindlessly) and ever since, my laptop immediately boots into Windows with the following error before:

```
Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

There doesn't appear to be anyway for me to boot into the Ubuntu side of the computer, currently.

I have searched through previous posts and have found similar issues, but unfortunately nothing that appears to be able to solve my issue. Boot manager appears to show that grubx64.efi is not presen in the boot/efi folder.

I tried to boot into a Ubuntu through a live USB stick boot, but was unable to find and fix whatever issue is present. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the Super Grub 2 disk would fix the bootloader doesn't recognize well.

Comment: UEFI update often resets all the settings to defaults. You need to review all the changes you made, Secure Boot off, Fast Boot off, AHCI, UEFI boot (not CSM/Legacy), and any others. I keep a list as I also change those but some other optional ones. But mine is not a Dell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility?

Use these commands to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

And then, launch it with `boot-repair` command and choose "Recommended repair".

Comment: Yes, I was able to use the boot repair utility yesterday and get it fixed!
Thank you for the suggestion.